# Google AutoML projects visibility

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have two google account (one private and one for business).

If I log in to my business account and navigate to AutoML I do land on the 'Specify Google Cloud project'. That's right. But when I want do select the associated GCP project the list that appears includes all projects that are part of my private google account.

I deleted all cookies, closed the browser and startet to log in (only to my business account) again -> the same happens again.

That's weird.

Do anyone else have this kind of behaviour? I don't see any connection between my private and my business account. Why do this happen?

I did not add any extra priviledges to the GPC project inside my private account.

Comment: can you access your business project from your private account? vice versa? can you see other projects?

Comment: No I can't access business projects from private account. I can see all my private projects in my business account, and only those. I even can't see my own business projects in my business account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try *signing out* of the AutoML UI? This is a multi-login issue related to the credentials used when you first logged into AutoML.

Comment: Signing in and out doesn't have any effects. Even using another browser on another computer solves the problem.

Comment: Hmm okay lemme take a closer look. Could you do me a favor and submit feedback in the AutoML UI, using the menu in the upper right? Its totally up to you, but I can best help if you mention JoshGC and the email addresses you sign into AutoML or the browser with.

Comment: Ok, I submitted a feedback.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'm not seeing anything unusual on our side. Can you clarify when you logged out, what did you log out of. Was it the Chrome browser? When you visit the AutoML UI, there is a menu in the upper right, that should show you "who" the UI thinks you are logged in as, and allow you to log out, of our service in particular

Comment: Today, I logged in with my business account to make screenshots of the behaviour, and I were surprised. The problems are gone. Now everythings works as expected. My private and my business account both could define own datasets in AutoML based on their own GCP project.
Maybe you fixed something "accidentally" or it was a self healing process...
Thanks.

Comment: There is some self-healing going on, both in our process and in your browser. Glad the issue is resolved for you.